# How to group and order by data in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to group by the following data by "country" and order by the "number" as showing as expected view in angularJS (using table, thead,tbody)?

```
$scope.players = [
  {country:, 'US', name: 'Gene', number: 2},
  {country:, 'CANADA', name: 'George', number: 2},
  {country:, 'US', name: 'Steve', number: 1},
  {country:, 'UK', name: 'Paula', number: 1},
  {country:, 'US', name: 'John', number: 3},
  {country:, 'CANADA', name: 'Joseph', number: 1},
];
```

**expected view in angularJS (using table, thead,tbody)**

```
Number  Name

CANADA

1   Joseph
2   George

SRI LANKA

1   Saman

UK

1   Paula

US

1   Steve
2   Gene
3   John
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#get-started) for some useful angularjs filters. The group by filter that this library provides can be used here.

your desired html can easily be achieved with something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="(key,value) in players | groupBy:'country'">
            <td colspan="2">
                {{key}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="player in value | orderBy:'number'">
            <td>{{player.number}}</td>
            <td>{{player.name}}</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also you should remove the stray commas from your $scope.players. It should look like this

```
$scope.players = [
  {country: 'US', name: 'Gene', number: 2},
  {country: 'CANADA', name: 'George', number: 2},
  {country: 'US', name: 'Steve', number: 1},
  {country: 'UK', name: 'Paula', number: 1},
  {country: 'US', name: 'John', number: 3},
  {country: 'CANADA', name: 'Joseph', number: 1}];
```